# How to remove white borders around X-ray image with OpenCV Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have thousands of X-ray images of the left hand. All of these images have thin white borders surrounding them.

I want to create a function (OpenCV/numpy) that will allow me to just auto remove/crop these thin white borders out or replace them with black/gray color.

[image]

[image]

**First image is the original image, second image is the output with white borders removed. Is this even possible?**

Note: For some images, the white borders aren't always surrounding the image, instead there can be white bars on the sides of the image --> [Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdmTU.jpg)

Comment: maybe simply always crop it - get without some marging ie. 10 pixels - `image[10:-10, 10:-10]`

Comment: This is actually not a bad idea, I haven't thought about that.

Comment: I would recommend cropping too. the answer given below just paints over the edges, giving you a "frame"... that contains nothing useful. simply just crop. -- your second image **is** the first but cropped. how did you make that and why did you not find any material that shows you how to crop images in numpy arrays?

Comment: Oh I just used Photoshop to crop the white border out. I just googled how to crop or remove white borders in images on google and I mostly got using PIL or OpenCV. 

But this makes so much sense, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do the job:

```
import cv2


def fix_border(image,x_pad,y_pad,col):
    image=image.copy()
    image[:y_pad,:]=col
    image[-y_pad:,:]=col
    image[:,:x_pad] = col
    image[ :,-x_pad:] = col
    return image


img = cv2.imread("Path to image")

img = fix_border(img,20,20,(50,50,50))
cv2.imshow("",img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: This looks promising. But would it be possible to perhaps thin out the grey border? Because when I use this on my images, I get a thicker grey border.

Comment: Second and third parameters for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

Look carefully, the image was just cropped. It is smaller.

[image]